# YUI: specify fallback in case loading script from CDN fails?

Tags: javascript, yui

Hey is there a way to specify a fallback js just in case loading from the YUI CDN were to fail?

Comment: "CDN were to fail" A little too paranoid here?

Comment: haha yeah, not a likely possibility, but it is still an interesting question to me. More likely one of my own scripts would fail to load :P.

Comment: @Yi Jiang  //  I can understand as well... we've got scripts on a local server and every now and then we'll catch one where we left the Google CDN referenced... inevitably, someone without a connection to the outside world (usually using IE6, to boot) will call and complain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to check for the existence of the global object/function created by the script. For instance, for jQuery it would be

```
typeof jQuery === 'undefined';
```

and YUI I believe is

```
typeof YUI === 'undefined';
```

Then you might want to try injecting the script in some other manner, like

```
if(typeof YUI === 'undefined'){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "some/other/source.js";
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

This will create a new `script` element in your `head` with a link to another source of your choice.